# Override @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) from POJO in ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

***Question:*** Is it possible to override `Include.NON_NULL` defined in the POJO while creating the `ObjectMapper`?

***Explanation:***

Suppose I have a POJO as below:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class POJO {
  String name;
  String description;
  //Constructors, Getters & Setters, etc
}
```

And a test class as below:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    POJO p = new POJO();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     String jsonString = mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS)
                               .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                               .writeValueAsString(p);
    //jsonString should contain empty name & description fields, but they doesn't
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a mix-in, since it has priority over annotations.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class MixIn {
}
```

And add it to the mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(POJO.class, MixIn.class);
```

The result will be

```
{"name":null,"description":null}
```

Comment: It works, but only if the mix-in is configured for a specific type. If we configure the mix-in for Object.class so that it is applicable for all types, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why such a behaviour?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but what you can do, if you don't want the annotations, is disable them. You can use `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);`
Then all the configuration will be in the ObjectMapper.

Comment: How can we disable only class-level annotations? Want to keep the Property level annotations.