# Local override for setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL) in ObjectMapper

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

In my spring application in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, CustomObjectMapper is added in HttpMessageConverter. The CustomObjectMapper has  setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL). For 1 particular pojo returned via Spring's ResponseBody I want null properties to be returned as well. I cannot change global setting as it will impact all controllers endpoints. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mixin for the Pojo of interest and set the mixin on your CustomObjectMapper. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571979/override-jsonincludeinclude-non-null-from-pojo-in-objectmapper) shows exactly how to do this.

Comment: yes, i have used mixin now. Thanks. However earlier mixin was not working as it seems mixin does not work with JaxbAnnotationIntrospector. I added JacksonAnnotationIntrospector along and mixin worked.